# Need a little info on the Apple dev program

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have searched everywhere but just can't seem to find the answer. Can you make an app for your own personal use if your not an official developer, like paying the $99/yr. I am a member of the developer program, I think, I can login but I don't pay the 99. I have made an app that I would really like to try out on my iPhone but have no idea how to... Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make it clear. You have two other options:

1- Share a developer profile with a friend  as long as you both are using it for development purpose only.

2- Jailbreak your device. "I am against that option"

3- Register for the paid developer program.

Answer (score 4):

No. Part of what the 99 bucks gets you is the ability to run builds on your device(s).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot build to a device without the paid developer program, but I believe Apple will deactivate your account if you never send in an app submission to the app store.